# When making changes in GCP - Google Cloud Console, is there a way to view corresponding commands for gcloud cli?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-developers-console, google-deployment-manager

As I'm making changes within the GCP - Google Cloud Console, I like to capture equivalent gcloud cli commands for automation use later.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, on Compute engine and GKE, on creation only. But not on other services. I already asked this to Google. Try to open a feature request to increase the requirement of that!!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Guillaume blaquiere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11372593/guillaume-blaquiere), you have an option on the bottom of the resource creation page for GCE, GKE, VPC Network, etc.

Look like this:
[image]